# datetimepicker block dates from the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker code that i use for hotel booking which i block all the days before today date along with the booked days.
i have two datetimepicker inputs, first datetimepicker is for checkin and the second is for checkout

its working fine but if i have lets say : 20 of april as a blocked day and i select the checkin from 1 till 22 then i still have day 20 selected in between.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function(){
 $(document).ready(function () {
var arrDisabledDates = {};
arrDisabledDates[new Date('03/22/2018')] = new Date('03/22/2018');
arrDisabledDates[new Date('04/20/2018')] = new Date('04/20/2018');
arrDisabledDates[new Date('05/16/2018')] = new Date('05/16/2018');
arrDisabledDates[new Date('06/30/2018')] = new Date('06/30/2018');

$('#dt2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate:  0, 
    inline: true,
     beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
        var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[dt];
        if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
        else return [true, '', ''];
    }
});

$("#dt1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
    minDate:  0,
 inline: true,
    onSelect: function(date){            
        var date1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');           
        var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) ); 
        date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );        
        var newDate = date.toDateString(); 
        newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );                      
        $('#dt2').datepicker("option","minDate",newDate);            
    },
    beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
        var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[dt];
        if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
        else return [true, '', ''];
    }

});



});

});



</script>
```

check in :

```
<input type="text" name="dt1" id="dt1">
```

check out:

```
<input type="text" name="dt2" id="dt2">
```

again my code is working fine but if i have lets say : 20 of april as a blocked day and i select the checkin from 1 till 22 then i still have day 20 selected in between.

what i want to do is to block selecting any dates that have a blocked day in between the first and the second inputs...

guess am using the jquery ui datetimepicker..

Comment: So if I'm understanding your question correctly, you want your user to be able to select a date range using two separate datetime picker controls, but block out some special dates when they go to select the date range, if one of the blocked dates happens to fall within the range. Looking at the code you posted, it appears that you're hooking into the onSelect function of `#dt1` setting the `minDate` property on `#dt2`...but there is no select handler on `#dt2`

Comment: It's hard to tell how you're sending the dates to your server. Do you need to show in the UI that the date is blocked out somehow?...and if that's the case are you keeping track of all the selected dates in the client somewhere and sending them all to the server, or are you just sending the start and end dates. As a side note--it's not a good idea to rely on client validation when you send your form data to the server. Make sure your server is also validating your blocked dates as well.

Comment: After the post is sent the server will validate the data , but i need to stop the client from selecting a blocked date in the date range from the input selection from the beginning....

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to make sure the dates are not selected in the control even if the user selects a range where a blocked date falls within the range, maybe try always deselecting any blocked dates in the `onSelect` function for `#dt2`?

```
$('#dt2').datepicker({
        ...
        onSelect: () => { 
           for(let date in arrDisabledDates) {
               //deselect date (not sure which datetimepicker library you're using              
               $("#dt2")._clearDate(date); //example

           }
        }
        ...
});
```

Comment: yes that exactly what am trying to do , but the code is not working ....

Comment: which datetime picker library are you using?

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker.html

Comment: If you're using that library then all of the code in your `beforeShowDay` function seems unnecessary since the library provides a `disabledDates` property which takes an array. You have a variable called `arrDisabledDates`, which is defined as an object with Dates as keys (which I would assume it's just calling `Date.toString()` to populate the keys anyway), so maybe just try using a normal array `[new Date('03/22/2018'), new Date('04/20/2018'), ...etc]` and setting the `disabledDates` property with that. You may not need `beforeShowDay` at all to accomplish what you want.

Comment: tried :     disabledDates: ['04/22/2018','04/21/2018'],
not working... any idea on modifying my code?

Comment: guess am using the jquery ui datetimepicker

Comment: I guess what's confusing me is how you're showing the user that they have a range of dates selected, other than implying it with 2 dates. There's not code in your post that handles anything like that. If a user selects 4/1 in `#dt1` and 4/22 for `#dt2` is there some other piece of code outside of what you've posted that listens for change and manually "selects" those dates in between to be highlighted in the control? If so, that is where you would put code to ignore selecting any date in your list of disabled dates. What you have in `beforeShowDate` works fine to disable dates initially.